# Plugin Recommendation: Slideshow Gallery Delayed Image Loadging

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I am wondering if there is a WordPress plugin that creates a slideshow of images where:

*flash isn't used

*images are not all loaded at once and instead are loaded after page load

I have a requirement for numerous images to be present in a slideshow that are high res. All images need to be stored locally (e.g. no flickr).

I took a cruise through one or two plugins but they include all the images at once. Which murders page load times.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Really Simple Slideshow and manually integrating it into WordPress. Here is a link if this helps anyone:

http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/